\biguplus downward facing version
I need a symbol that is a set intersection sign (\cap) with a plus sign inside it. This would be a variant of \biguplus (where I don't need the "big" part) for the \cap case (upside-down U with "plus" sign inside).

It does not even seem to be in unicode, even though there are some other variants of caps.

Curious why you mention \biguplus but not \uplus. Have you tried \rotatebox[origin=c]{180}{$\uplus$} (requires the graphicx package)?

Did not know \uplus. Would you know if there is a version where the plus sign is above the intersection sign?

@ExpressionCoder - You mean $\overset{+}{\cap}$? (Requires the amsmath package.)

Yes. That's it, thanks!

I will assume that you will only need to typeset the rotated version of \uplus in TeX's text-style or display-style math mode. (Please let me know if this assumption is not appropriate.)
Assuming you need the "plus" symbols in \uplus and its rotated counterpart to line up vertically, the following implementation of \vplus may be what you're looking for. If you don't need the vertical alignment, just omit the \raisebox wrapper.
The following screenshot shows \uplus, \vplus, and two variants of placing a + symbol above a \cap symbol side by side.

\documentclass[10pt]{article} % or '11pt', or '12pt'

\usepackage{graphicx}  % for '\rotatebox' macro
\usepackage{amsmath}   % for '\overset' macro
\newcommand\vplus{\mathbin{\raisebox{0.125ex}{%
   \rotatebox[origin=c]{180}{$\uplus$}}}}

\begin{document}

${\uplus}
 {\vplus}
 {\overset{+}{\cap}}
 {\overset{\scriptscriptstyle+}{\cap}}$

\end{document}


I do need the \cap (as specified in the question) with a plus sign in it. The upside down U seems a solution, but may not display the same as a regular \cap sign would.

@ExpressionCoder - Please clarify what you mean by "The upside down [`\cup] .. may not display the same as a regular `\cap` sign would". Which properties of the symbols raise your concern?

It is surprising that Unicode math supports \uplus but there is no equivalent for 180 degree rotated of it. So, we have to rotate it manually. What we can do in OpTeX, if we want to define rotated \vplus:
\fontfam[lm]

\def\vplus{\mathbin{\mathstyles
   {\raise\dobystyle{1.4}{1.4}{1}{.7}ex\rotbox{180}{$\currstyle\uplus$}}}}

$A\uplus B$, $A\vplus B$

$\scriptstyle A\vplus B$, $\scriptscriptstyle A\vplus B, A \uplus B$

\bye


Flip \uplus vertically and raise by the depth.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\vplus}{\mathbin{\mathpalette\vplus@\relax}}
\newcommand{\vplus@}[2]{%
  \raisebox{\depth}{\scalebox{1}[-1]{$\m@th#1\uplus$}}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

$a\vplus b\uplus c$

$\scriptstyle a\vplus b\uplus c$

\end{document}


Note.
The symbol \uplus is sometimes used to denote that the two sets involved in the union are disjoint. It's also used for “multiset sum”, where the multiplicities of elements are summed.
There is no dual notion in either case, which explains why the flipped symbol doesn't exist.

Thanks for the clarification on use.
